# New linux user and their password

Tags: ubuntu, users, password

In Ubuntu, there is a GUI option when creating new users:

1. Allow user to set a password when they next login
2. Set a password now

What would be the command line equivalent to this ?

From what I've been able to determine, useradd or adduser don't provide this option.

I know I can set a password and expire it forcing the user to change it but that's not the same thing exactly.

This would be for NEW users who have never logged on, and giving them the privilege to set their password for themselves at the first login.

I know if the GUI can do it can be done, but can't find it anywhere in man pages or internet searches.....

Comment: Welcome, I think you are looking for `sudo passwd -e username`.

Comment: I found that if I combine passwd -d the passwd -e, I get the desired result.

The command would be passwd -de $USER

passwd -d removes the password
passwd -e expires the password

Then, when the user goes to login the the FIRST time there is NO password in existence but the machine requires that user to set one.  

This eliminates me having to set a bogus passwd like "PASSWORD" and telling the USER that so they can login and change it something of their own choosing.

Answer (score 7):

There's a program called `passwd` that does that: change your own password, or if you're root, change any user's password.

`sudo passwd -e yegnal` can be used to set a password for the user `yegnal` to *expire* the next time they log in (so they have to pick a new one).

`-d` sets the user passwordless – so anyone can login without a password. So, `sudo passwd -d -e yegnal` will make `yegnal` be passwordless and enforce setting a new password next time they log in.

A note on security: it's probably a bad idea to set up a user account without a password, no matter whether you do it via GUI or CLI. What's the point? Creating a user takes literally seconds, so you can create one (eg. logged in as root via SSH from afar) whenever you need one, and use a random password that you expire instantly and share with the new human user anyways.

Comment: I found that if I combine passwd -d the passwd -e, I get the desired result.

The command would be passwd -de $USER

passwd -d removes the password
passwd -e expires the password

Then, when the user goes to login the the FIRST time there is NO password in existence but the machine requires that user to set one.  

This eliminates me having to set a bogus passwd like "PASSWORD" and telling the USER that so they can login and change it something of their own choosing.

Comment: as said, that's not good security practice, but you do you! *any password*, even just two words from a dictionary that are easy to tell, is better than no password.